# Can't get JTextField user input to search text file to work

Tags: java

Can't seem to get scanner to match the user input from JTextField to the text file. For example: Search employee number 1121 and see who it is. Number & Name from text file

UPDATED: Full Code With Changes Below

```
public class custSearch extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public JTextField userInput;

// Declaring Window Name, Size & Functions
public custSearch(){
    super ("Customer Records");
    setSize(630,250);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //NumberFormat integerFieldFormatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    //integerFieldFormatter.setGroupingUsed(false);

// Declaring JPanels & New FlowLayouts  
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(-2));

// Declaring JLabels    
    JLabel cs = new JLabel("Search Phone Number:"); 

// Declaring JButtons
    JButton sb1 = new JButton("Search");

// Declaring JFormattedTextFields
    //JFormattedTextField cNumber = new JFormattedTextField(integerFieldFormatter);
    //cNumber.setColumns(7);
    JTextField cNumber = new JTextField();
    cNumber.setColumns(7);

// Declaring JPanel Layout
    p1.add(cs);
    p1.add(cNumber);
    p1.add(sb1);
    add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //Create File & Save Details
    //sb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        //@Override
    //  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //      File file = new File("Customers.txt");
    //      try{
    //      if(file.exists()==false){
    //              file.createNewFile();
    //      }
    //      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    //      pw.println(cNumber.getText());
    //      pw.close();
    //      }catch(IOException e1){
    //          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html>Customer File Could Not Be Created<p>Make Sure Program Has File Write Perssions");
    //      }

    //}
    //});
    sb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Customers.txt"))) {
                while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    int cNumber = sc.nextInt();
                    if(cNumber == Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText()))
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer Found" + cNumber);
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");

            }

        }

    });
}
}
```

Getting this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at custSearch$1.actionPerformed(custSearch.java:83)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite hard to figure out the problem with the code you provided. Could you provide the whole class and the error that you encounter? Also you seem to use assignment operator in your if statement:

```
if(sc = cNumber);
```

The correct form for if statements is:

```
if() {

}
```

or:

```
if()
    only one line allowed;
```

and you seem to assign Scanner to int variable. cNumber contains your next token so I guess what you have to do is do something like

```
if(cNumber == 1121) etc..
```

In case say you have

```
private JTextField userInput;
```

It must be visible to your actionPerformed(), then you can do the following:

```
if(cNumber == Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText())) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer Found" + cNumber);
}
```

So try to write something like this:

```
      @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Customers.txt"))) {
                while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    int cNumber = sc.nextInt();
                    if(cNumber == Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText()))
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer Found" + cNumber);
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
            }
```

**UPDATE TRY CREATING SIMILAR CODE:** Sorry your code was hard to follow as I didn't have the other components such as the class that it inherits from so what I created is a simple version of what you might need, sorry I was kind of in a hurry so I wasn't able to comment it very well if you have any questions feel free to ask! Basically it does what you want, just make sure you have Customer.txt in the same folder as your src folder.

So here it is:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTextField numberTextField;
    private JButton submitButton;

    public Test() {
        setTitle("Get Phone Number");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(600, 300);
        setResizable(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create TextField, Label and Button
        add(new JLabel("Search Phone Number:"));
        numberTextField = new JTextField(10);
        add(numberTextField);
        submitButton = new JButton("Search");
        add(submitButton);

        //Adding action listener to the button
        submitButton.addActionListener(this);

        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public void findNumber(String path, int number) {
        File file = new File(path);

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

            while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int i = sc.nextInt();
                if(i == number) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Phone Number: " + number + " is found!");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    if(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry  phone number: " + number + " is not found!");
                        break;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        findNumber("Customers.txt", Integer.parseInt(numberTextField.getText()));
    }
}
```

Comment: the full colon in your one line if example is not valid Java

Comment: I will give it a try. I am still learning Java so thats why I had rookie mistakes lol.

Comment: @AlenEviLL I just get a red line error here (userInput.getText())). I know userInput was an example but nothing I put here is allowed other the "text" or null ?

Comment: @AlenEviLL made private JTextField userInput;  Code compiles enter number is search box press search nothing happens no errors?

Comment: @AlenEviLL ok got an error. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at custSearch$1.actionPerformed(custSearch.java:83)
 which is this line if(cNumber == Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText()))

Comment: @Sparish hi sorry I was away for a bit, look at the updated section, I created a function that takes the path of your file in this case it is just "Customer.txt" and a number to find, as you can see I'm getting it from the textField using Integer.parseInt(). I tested this code and seemed to work for me. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: @AlenEviLL  Thanks man. I see its running good now. I trying to self learn java only been doing it for less then 1 month. Now is there I way I could get it to read the whole line? What I mean if I add this to the customer.txt..  1127:Steve

Comment: @Sparish no problem, glad could help, also started Java few month ago but I am at university so I guess it is easier for me :) Just keep practicing. Well there are several ways to do this, if you know that for example number is always 4 digits (I assume usually phone numbers are fixed number of digits), then you could use something like String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex); and set beginIndex at 4 and the endIndex at (str.length - 1); Then this string will contain only letters from 4 till the end which presumably will be the name, if you don't know the length then you could

Comment: @Sparish use regular expressions but it is a bit complicated :D